# Rendering an Assimp Scene object in XNA without DirectX or OpenGL

Tags: xna, rendering, scene, assimp

Is there any site that explains how to render an imported Assimp Scene object in XNA/MonoGame using only the Frameworks available in those libraries? I realize that would be at the Vertex/Matrix level but that is what I am trying to learn. The site would preferably start with the basics of rendering a mesh from the Scene object and then move on to Materials or Textures. A bonus would be if it could include information about Animating from the Scene object.

Comment: You can't use XNA/Monogame without using DirectX/OpenGL in the background.

Comment: I just meant not entering Microsoft.DirectX using statement in my XNA code. I realize XNA uses DirectX in the background but I wanted to know how to render using only the methods in Xna.Framework.Graphics. Like the VertexBuffer and IndexBuffer